# How should I go about using jQuery extend when my config file has a normal array in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, key, extend

Seems `$.extend` uses only the keys of its input to determine what to overwrite. So when my config looks like this

```
var config = {
    "numeric" : false,
    "keycode_whitelist" : [
        37, 39, // Left, right
        9,      // Tab
        17,     // Ctrl
        116     // F5
    ]
};
```

and is extended with more keycodes to add to the whitelist, extend simply overwrites the defaults with the new keycodes one by one even though they are different values.

I'm thinking about solving this problem by typing the keys like this `37: 37, 39: 39` etc. I would love a solution that doesn't force me to mess up the syntax of my configuration though.

Comment: I just like the name, codemonkey...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to use [merge](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge/) instead of extend:

```
var config = {
    "numeric": false,
    "keycode_whitelist": [
        37, 39, // Left, right
        9, // Tab
        17, // Ctrl
        116 // F5
    ]
};

var custom = {
    "somevalue": "some other things",
    "keycode_whitelist": [
        1, 2, 3
        ]
};
var newopts = $.extend({}, config, custom);
newopts.keycode_whitelist = $.merge(custom.keycode_whitelist, config.keycode_whitelist);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3Q4cF/2/

**Update:**

To merge every single array:

```
$.each(config, function(key, obj){
    if($.isArray(obj)) {
        if(custom[key]) {
           newopts[key] = $.merge(config[key], custom[key]);
        }
    }
} );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Q4cF/5/

Comment: I think `if (console)` will make error in below IE8. It should be `if (window.console)`. Anyway, lovely answer.:)

Comment: Well I can't really use merge instead of extend, since I'm extending the whole config object, not just the whitelist keys. I guess I'll have to manually merge every property of config :-(